# seekbar and mediaplayer android

Tags: android, seekbar

I am using seekbar and mediaplayer for a chat app to send and listen voice recorders , I have tried all solutions but seekbar doesn't run with me
my code in adapter

```
private void updateseek()
    {
        if(player!=null) {

            seekBar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
            if(player.isPlaying())
            {
                runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                     updateseek();
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,100);
            }
            else {
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
            }
        }
    }
//and i call it in getview in adapter : 
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                    seekBar.setMax(player.getDuration());
                                    player.start();
                                    updateseek();

                                }
                            });
```

and I also implemented **setOnSeekBarChangeListener** to seekbar , but not working

Comment: how exactly is it not working?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko seekbar doesn't move

Comment: You update seekbar position only once

Comment: code looks OK. Have you checked with debugger, where the execution goes in IFs, which code is executed, etc?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes I have checked it and updateseek() is executed, and iam also make Log to show player. getcurrentposition() and all positions displayed, but seekBar.setprogress() not working

Comment: are you sure that the `handler` you are using is using the main thread looper?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko how can I make sure ? , can you more explain ?

Comment: how do you create that handler?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko , I create it once , in the constructor of adapter

Comment: @SergeyGlotov how ?i am calling setprogress() everytime ? ,

Comment: You call `updateSeek()` once in `onPrepared()` callback. `updateSeek()` set progress to current and runs Runnable (once too). Do you set progress somewhere else?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov yes , i set it in setOnSeekBarChangeListener